# Update XML node value with ampersand in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file, let's call it Project.params with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SSIS:Parameters xmlns:SSIS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS">
  <SSIS:Parameter SSIS:Name="MyPassword">
    <SSIS:Properties>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ID">{8ff4ab3f-e607-4ccc-adc0-bececa310d17}</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="CreationName">
      </SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Description">
      </SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="IncludeInDebugDump">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Required">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Sensitive">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Value">ZP</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="DataType">18</SSIS:Property>
    </SSIS:Properties>
  </SSIS:Parameter>
</SSIS:Parameters>
```

I need to update the "MyPassword" property with a string that has an ampersand. I tried the following code

```
$sourcePath = "C:\Project.params"
$Parameters = @{}
$key = "MyPassword"
#$value = "aabbcc"
$value = "aabbcc&"
$Parameters.add($key, $value)

[xml]$paramxml = Get-Content $sourcePath

    $paramxml.Parameters.Parameter | ? { $_.Name -eq $key} |
            % {
                $parameterxmlnode = $_
                $parameterxmlnode.Properties.Property | ? {$_.Name -eq "Value"} |
                % {
                    $oldval = $_
                    if ($oldval.InnerText -ne $value)
                    {
                        Write-Host "Updating property" $key "..."
                        $oldval.set_InnerXML($value)
                        $ismodified = $true
                    }
                }
            }
```

I get the following error

```
Exception calling "set_InnerXml" with "1" argument(s): "Unexpected end of file has occurred. Line 1, position 7."
At line:22 char:25
+                         $oldval.set_InnerXML($value)
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

However, if I just remove the ampersand from the `$value` variable, everything works as expected. Can someone please help?

Comment: `&` is a special symbol for XML and should be encoded properly.

Comment: What should I do then? I have no control over the password of the server. How can I encode it ?

Comment: @BICube `$password.Replace('&','&amp;')`

Comment: *What should I do then?* You should use methods, which handle encoding for you (for example `InnerText`). `InnerXml` expect valid XML fragment, but not an arbitrary text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` needs to be escaped as `&amp;`, as does quotes and angle brackets.

You can use [`SecurityElement.Escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(VS.80).aspx) to escape the entire string for you:

```
$escapedValue = [System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($value)
$oldval.InnerXML = $escapedValue
```

... or, as @PetSerAl suggests, use the appropriate property `InnerText` (rather than `InnerXml`), this will take care of the escaping automatically:

```
$oldval.InnerText = $value
```

Comment: wasn't aware of that escape means Nice @mathias-r-jessen

Comment: Why call to some other API for escapement, when XML DOM already have all necessary methods to do that?

Comment: That did it. Thanks @Mathias

Comment: @PetSerAl `SecurityElement.Escape()` was just the first thing that came to mind. What are you suggesting exactly?

Comment: `$oldval.InnerText = $value`

Comment: @PetSerAl doesn't work, triggers the error OP posted. [Try this](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/e3456eb6b65545a8123da61917b3ac57)

Comment: OP set `InnerXml` not `InnerText`.

Comment: @PetSerAl that also worked. Thanks to both of you guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for:

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SSIS:Parameters xmlns:SSIS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/SSIS">
  <SSIS:Parameter SSIS:Name="MyPassword">
    <SSIS:Properties>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="ID">{8ff4ab3f-e607-4ccc-adc0-bececa310d17}</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="CreationName">
      </SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Description">
      </SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="IncludeInDebugDump">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Required">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Sensitive">0</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="Value">ZP</SSIS:Property>
      <SSIS:Property SSIS:Name="DataType">18</SSIS:Property>
    </SSIS:Properties>
  </SSIS:Parameter>
</SSIS:Parameters>
'@
$xml.Parameters.Parameter.Name
$xml.Parameters.Parameter.Name = '&MyPassword'
$xml.Parameters.Parameter.Name
```

Comment: Thanks Thom. I was actually looking to update the value of that property not the name of the property itself.

Comment: ok I see now what you are after. Seems Mathias Beat me to it.